# Jquery wrap() как сделать

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 3 дива с классом `.fc`, как с помощью jquery объединить сразу 3 элемента в одну обертку, мой скрипт оборачивает каждый див в обертку.

```
function resize(){
if($(window).width() <= 768) {
  $('.advantages-wrap-left, .advantages-wrap-right').contents().unwrap();
 } else{
 $('.fd').wrapAll('<div class="advantages-wrap-left"></div>');
 $('.fc').wrapAll('<div class="advantages-wrap-right"></div>');
 }
 }
 window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').addListener(function(e){
  if(e.matches) resize();
   else resize();
})
  resize();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  advMonster();
});

function advMonster() {
  var advWrapped;

  onResize();
  $(window).on('resize', onResize);

  function onResize() {
    var items = $('.advantages-item');

    if($(window).width() <= 768) {
      if(advWrapped) {
        advWrapped = false;
        items.unwrap();
      }
    } else {
      if(!advWrapped || advWrapped === undefined) {
          advWrapped = true;
          items.filter('.fd').wrapAll('<div class="advantages-wrap-left" />');
          items.filter('.fc').wrapAll('<div class="advantages-wrap-right" />');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, я вот тестировал, и заметил, что если медленно расширять браузер, не срабатывает. В любом случае, вариант я ваш оставлю )

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66053/discussion-on-answer-by-medvedevdev-jquery-wrap--).

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

Comment: я поправил немного скрипт как он есть на самом деле, возможно из-за того, что у меня идет через resize, метод wrapAll начинает добавлять бесконечное колличество оберток если экран больше 768. не подходит такой способ (

Comment: Может вместо wrap/unwrap добавлять и удалять класс? Или ещё можно воспользоваться media queries

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы на больших экранах элементы были в обертке, а на маленьких эти обертки должны удаляться из dom. Иначе не получится адаптировать блоки как мне нужно

Comment: Хорошо, понятно. Попробуй заменить `$('.advantages-item').unwrap();` на `$('.advantages-wrap-left .advantages-item.fd').unwrap();` и такой же для `.fc`

Answer (score 0):

Можно для индексации использовать метод .slice() и после использовать тот-же wrapAll.

Comment: Надо как-то поподробнее писать... Пока больше на комментарий тянет